# Cómo imprimir los datos que resultan de un for en Python en una sola línea?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy aprendiendo y practicando, y me propuse hacer un generador de Alias de cbu. Usé el módulo random. Mi problema es que al hacer el bucle para no repetir código me imprime las palabras random que generé en lineas diferentes. Pongo ejemplo de cómo lo hice con funciones y sin:

```
nombre =input("Ingrese su nombre: ").lower()
apellido = input("Ingrese su apellido: ").lower()

listadepalabras = ["peregrino", "lima", "primavera", "pedazo", "golpe", "falsa", "mesa", 
"casamiento", "gato", "átomo", "galletita", "programa", "boton", "tinta", "señora", "pala", 
"pelo", "encendedor", "raton", "prima", "numero", "carta", "muro", "arabe", "jefa", "rojo", 
"coche", "bebe", "uñas", "manos", "serie", "medias", "abrelatas"]

def Elimina(palabra, lista):
    list(lista).remove(palabra)

if len(nombre) > 3 and len(apellido) < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        palabra = random.choice(listadepalabras)
        Elimina(palabra, listadepalabras)
        print(palabra)
```

También lo hice así, sin usar funciones y sí funciono, pero es más largo:

```
elif len(nombre) < 5 and len(apellido) > 6:
    palabraelegida1_1 = random.choice(listadepalabras[5:9])
    listadepalabras.remove(palabraelegida1_1)
    palabraelegida1_2 = random.choice(listadepalabras[5:9])
    listadepalabras.remove(palabraelegida1_2)
    palabraelegida1_3 = random.choice(listadepalabras[5:9])
    listadepalabras.remove(palabraelegida1_3)
    cbucaso2 = print(palabraelegida1_1 + "." + palabraelegida1_2 + "." + palabraelegida1_3)
```

Nunca pregunté acá asi que pido disculpas por ser desordenada, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Puedes hacer lo siguiente:**

Una una variable donde almacenes estos valores que deseas presentar, por ejemplo en un `str` y después cuando hayas culminado lo presentas. Algo como esto:

```
palabras = ''
if len(nombre) > 3 and len(apellido) < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        palabra = random.choice(listadepalabras)
        Elimina(palabra, listadepalabras)
        palabras += palabra+', '
        
    print(palabras[:-2])
```

También lo puedes hacer con una lista, o con cualquier otra variable que desees.

**Nota:** En el `print` se pone `[:-2]` haciendo referencia a que presente todos los caracteres del `str` menos los últimos 2 caracteres.

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto, en mi caso solo tenía que eliminar el último carácter porque los alias se separan con puntos. Mil gracias de verdad! :´)

Comment: @JuliSabatino si te sirvió, acepta la respuesta como valida.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo pasandole el parametro  **end** a print()

ejemplo:

```
import random
nombre =input("Ingrese su nombre: ").lower()
apellido = input("Ingrese su apellido: ").lower()

listadepalabras = ["peregrino", "lima", "primavera", "pedazo", "golpe", "falsa", "mesa", 
"casamiento", "gato", "átomo", "galletita", "programa", "boton", "tinta", "señora", "pala", 
"pelo", "encendedor", "raton", "prima", "numero", "carta", "muro", "arabe", "jefa", "rojo", 
"coche", "bebe", "uñas", "manos", "serie", "medias", "abrelatas"]

def Elimina(palabra, lista):
    list(lista).remove(palabra)

if len(nombre) > 3 and len(apellido) < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        palabra = random.choice(listadepalabras)
        Elimina(palabra, listadepalabras)
        print(palabra, end=' ')
```

o puede concatenar un string ejemplo:

```
import random
resultado = ""
nombre =input("Ingrese su nombre: ").lower()
apellido = input("Ingrese su apellido: ").lower()

listadepalabras = ["peregrino", "lima", "primavera", "pedazo", "golpe", "falsa", "mesa", 
"casamiento", "gato", "átomo", "galletita", "programa", "boton", "tinta", "señora", "pala", 
"pelo", "encendedor", "raton", "prima", "numero", "carta", "muro", "arabe", "jefa", "rojo", 
"coche", "bebe", "uñas", "manos", "serie", "medias", "abrelatas"]

def Elimina(palabra, lista):
    list(lista).remove(palabra)

if len(nombre) > 3 and len(apellido) < 10:
    for i in range(3):
        palabra = random.choice(listadepalabras)
        Elimina(palabra, listadepalabras)
        resultado +=  palabra + " " 
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Genial! No sabía que existía esa función dentro de print, mil gracias. Terminé haciéndolo creando una variable vacía como en tu segundo ejemplo. Te agradezco mucho :´)